# How to delay Paypal Payment for specific time

Tags: php

I have to delay paypal payment for the specific number of days. I am using paypal adaptive payment API for payments and i successfully gets the PayKey. I have to pay after 7days of request. Can anyone guide me how to complete payment after 7 days. Right now it returns me paymentExecStatus = CREATED. How can i COMPLETE this payment using payKey with cURL PHP?

Thanks